# Figuring out the difference in hours between two 24-hour times in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a data set for appointments with start and end times for each appointment. I need to calculate the amount of time the appointment lasted in hours, but the two fields are in 24-hour time and formatted as `INTEGER`. To make things even worse they're formatted as both 3 and 4 character integers so `830` and `1630` for example, not `0830` and `1630`.

What would be the best way to create a column with the number of hours between those two columns? I've tried converting them to `CHAR` and then taking a substring of the last two, but I can't get it to work for both the 3 and 4 time lengths.

It currently looks like this:

```
╔═══════════╦═════════╗
║ startTime ║ endTime ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╣
║       830 ║    1600 ║
║       400 ║     800 ║
║      1350 ║    1400 ║
╚═══════════╩═════════╝
```

And I'd ideally like it to look something like this:

```
╔═══════════╦═════════╦═══════╗
║ startTime ║ endTime ║ Hours ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬═══════╣
║       830 ║    1600 ║ 7.5   ║
║       400 ║     800 ║ 4     ║
║      1350 ║    1400 ║ .5    ║
╚═══════════╩═════════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: `200` = `20:00` or `02:00`?

Comment: 200 = 2:00. And I apologize for calling it military time, forgive my ignorance.

Comment: i think my CASE statement i just posted will solve your issue, but this could have been much easier if you had just stored the datetime value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `startTime` and `endTime` are both integers, you can use simple modulo and division to separate minutes and hours.

The following expression will give you `startTime` in minutes:

```
startTime % 100 + (startTime / 100) * 60
```

You can do the same for `endTime` and subtract `endTime` from `startTime` to get an expression for the time difference in minutes:

```
(endTime % 100 + (endTime / 100) * 60) - (startTime % 100 + (startTime / 100) * 60)
```

Finally, convert it to hours:

```
((endTime % 100 + (endTime / 100) * 60) - (startTime % 100 + (startTime / 100) * 60)) / 60.0
```

<sup>Note the division by `60.0` (which is a float) instead of `60` (which is an integer), so that the final result will be float and not integer.</sup>

Your final SQL query should look like:

```
SELECT 
    startTime, 
    endTime, 
    (((endTime % 100 + (endTime / 100) * 60) - (startTime % 100 + (startTime / 100) * 60)) / 60.0) 
        AS diff 
    FROM appointments
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a helper function to convert the INT military time to the native DATETIME type of your SQL database:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(hh, dbo.fnConvertMilitary(StartTime), 
  dbo.fnConvertMilitary(EndTime)
FROM appointments
```

Refer to @AlonGubkin's great answer for the implementation of dbo.fnConvertMilitary.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE LEN(D)  
            WHEN 3 THEN <do your 3 digit logic here>
            ELSE <do your 4 digit logic here>
       END CASE
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `CAST` on the division of 100 to remove the decimals

```
(((`time_to` % 100 + CAST((`time_to` / 100) AS INT) * 60) - (`time_from` % 100 + CAST((`time_from` / 100) AS INT) * 60)) / 60.0)  AS diff
```

example:
time end: 2200
time start: 2030
will result to 1.2~ if you don't use `CAST`

Answer (score 0):

Use DateDiff and Format using the HH for 24 hour to find the difference

```
DurationMinutes=IsNull(DateDiff(Minute,MyField1,'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm'),Format(MyField2,'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm')),0)
```