# Subtracting Overlapping Appointment Times From Each Other Using 24-Hour Time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, schedule

I am running a query against a table that holds appointment information for different clinicians. Each row is a different block of time that can be given different designations (such as appointment, available, not available) it includes a date field and two fields for start time and end time that are both stored as integers and formatted in 24-hour time (I don't have any control over the data base so I can't change this to a regular datetime format) from my last question I already know how to convert them to standard times and calculate the duration of the appointment from there.

[Figuring out the difference in hours between two 24-hour times in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20806643/figuring-out-the-difference-in-hours-between-two-24-hour-times-in-sql)

I need to be able to figure out how much available time a clinician has in the upcoming week. The way the system is set up is they designate blocks of time as "Available" and then people are able to fill in appointments over top of that available time. The available time and each of the appointments will be entered into the data base as it's own row and "available time" or "appointment" will be designated as the "type" for the time block.

The problem I have in trying to calculate the available time is that while appointments are scheduled over the available time the row for that available time stays the same in the database. So if there is a row for available time from 800 to 1430 and also an appointment on that same day for the same clinician from 800 to 1000 the row for the available time would still stay as 800 to 1430. I need a way to subtract the appointments from the blocks of available time when they overlap with them. So in the previous example it would say that the clinician still has 4.5 hours of available time instead of saying that there are 8.5 hours of available time. There may be cases where there are appointment on a day that do not overlap with a clinicians available time though, so just subtracting the two will not always work.

This is an example of what the data looks like and the current query I have for it:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a110e/1/0

I'm working in Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a110e/8

```
SELECT
ap.Staff,
ap.Date,
SUM(CAST((((EndTime % 100 + (EndTime / 100) * 60) - (BeginTime % 100 + (BeginTime / 100) * 60)) / 60.0) as DECIMAL(5,2))) as AvailableTime,
ud.Usedtime
FROM Appointments ap
JOIN 
(
  SELECT
  Staff,
  Date,
  SUM(CAST((((EndTime % 100 + (EndTime / 100) * 60) - (BeginTime % 100 + (BeginTime / 100) * 60)) / 60.0) as DECIMAL(5,2))) as UsedTime
  FROM Appointments ap
  WHERE Type <> 'Available'
  GROUP BY Staff, Date
  )  ud on ap.staff=ud.staff and ap.date=ud.date

WHERE Type = 'Available'

GROUP BY ap.Staff, ap.Date,ud.UsedTime
```

Comment: Well isn't calculating the available and the used hours it's know when to subtract the used hours from the available ones. So for John in the example you could just subtract used from available since they completely overlap time-wise. But with Ken you can't since his one appointment doesn't overlap with his available time so it wouldn't reduce his amount of available time. I mostly just need a way to indicate when an appointment, or part of one and how much, overlaps with available time.